# Is the set of sequences for which $\sum_{n=2}^\infty x_n=2x_1$ closed in $\ell_1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

In $\ell_1$ (with the $\ell_1$-norm), consider the subspace $M=\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty:\displaystyle{\sum_{n=2}^\infty x_n=2x_1}\}$.

I am trying to determine whether this space is closed or not and if its codimension is 1.

I have tried to find a sequence contained in $M$ that does not converge on $M$. However, everything I have come up with is convergent on $M$. I started to suspect $M$ may actually be closed, but I have been unable to to prove it.

Any hints would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $(x_n)_n\mapsto \sum x_n $ continuous? Is $(x_n)_n\mapsto x_1 $ continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x^{(n)})$ be a sequence in $M$ converging to some $x\in \ell^1$. We know that $2x_1=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2 x^{(n)}_1$, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^\infty x_k^{(n)}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty x_k$. As $2 x^{(n)}_1=\sum_{k=2}^\infty x_k^{(n)}$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$, we must have $x\in M$.

EDIT:
$M$ does has codimension $1$. My previous argument was incorrect. Indeed as pointed out by KeeperofSecrets $M$ is just the kernel of a continuous linear functional, and thus must have codimension $1$.

This is actually intuitively clear too, as any element in $M$ can be constructed by freely varying all the coordinates except the first one, and then fixing the first coordinate to be $-2$ multiplied by the sum of all the other coordinates, so the "degrees of freedom" of $M$ is only one less than for all of $\ell^1$.

Rigorously, we can notice that $e_1=[(1,0,0,\dots)]$ is a basis vector for $\ell^1/M$. Indeed for any $(x_n)\in \ell^1$ we note that
$$(x_n)-\left(x_1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty x_n,0,0,\dots\right)\in M,$$
so $[(x_n)]\in\operatorname{span}([e_1])$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more on why the fact that the spaces $S_n/M$ have trivial intersection implies that the codimension is not $1$?

Comment: Isn't $M$ the kernel of the continuous linear functional $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \mapsto -2x_1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty x_k$, and thus of codimension 1?

Comment: @ABC See my edit! I was mistaken.